Error Loading Dependencies Android Studio Kotlin
I was trying to Add some dependencies I found on GitHub here's the links to those dependencies
https://github.com/lincollincol/compose-audiowaveform
https://github.com/lincollincol/Amplituda
And here's how I add them
implementation ("com.github.lincollincol:compose-audiowaveform:1.1.2")
implementation ("com.github.lincollincol:amplituda:2.2.2")
I get these errors

Could not find com.github.lincollincol:compose-audiowaveform:1.1.2.
Searched in the following locations:

https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/lincollincol/compose-audiowaveform/1.1.2/compose-audiowaveform-1.1.2.pom
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/lincollincol/compose-audiowaveform/1.1.2/compose-audiowaveform-1.1.2.pom
Required by:
project :androidApp

Could not find com.github.lincollincol:amplituda:2.2.2.
Searched in the following locations:


did you check the latest version?

Yes those look to be the latest versions

https://github.com/lincollincol/compose-audiowaveform?tab=readme-ov-file#download
Make sure to add Jitpack in repositories.

Make sure you have below code in your project level gradle or settings.gradle.kts
 repositories {
       google()
       mavenCentral()
       maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }  //.gradle 
       or 
       maven { url = uri("https://jitpack.io") } //kts
    }


It's worked thank you so much guys
